# javascript change background color using if statement in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

please i always stuck with javascript that can't run in my php. i wanna change the background color on class one-container if the data on class one >= 100. the data come from db that i connect with my php.
any help would be appreciated.
thanks and sorry for my bad english

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">
<head>
  <title>Dashboard</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="body-container">

  <div class="sec-nav-container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <nav>
          <div class="title">
            <span class="dashboard">Dashboard Billing</span>
          </div>
          <div class="time-container">            
            <b class="last-updated">Last Updated on:</b>
              <script type="text/javascript">
                  function lastModified () {
                    document.write(document.lastModified);
                  }
                    lastModified();
              </script>
          </div>

        </nav>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="header-container">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <?php
            include "connect_db.php";

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_dashboard";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

              while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
                  echo " 
                      <div class='one-container'>
                          <h1 class='one'>" . $row['kirim_mpn'] . "</h1>
                          <p class='mpn'>Siap Kirim MPN</p>
                      </div>"; 
              }
            } 
              else {
                echo "Tidak ada hasil";
        }



        mysqli_close($conn);
      ?>
    </div>
    
  </div>

      </div>  

</div>

<script src="main.js"></script>
 <script language="JavaScript" src="emil.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is raw code of javascript that i wanna use in my php

```
<script>
var colorBox = function () {

    var data = [100];

    if (data >= 100) {
        document.getElementById("one-container").style.backgroundColor = '#FF6C60';
    } else {
        document.getElementById("one-container").style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
    }
}
colorBox();>
  
</script>
```

i wanna make var data = [100] become var data = [" . $row['kirim_mpn'] . "]

Comment: What exactly is stopping you? You know your condition, so if it gets true add the new class to the html

Comment: javascript on the second paragraph

Comment: Echo the whole script within the PHP so you can just use the php variables directly or echo the php within the js like do this in JS var data = [<?=$rdata >];....in your PHP $rdata = $row['kirim_mpn'];

Comment: thank u so much, finally it solved